# How to make row selected when moving between multiple views

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am working on xamarin.ios. I have a UITableView control at my view. I select a row in it and then move to next screen. If I come back to UITableView screen again the selected row doesn't highlight. It highlight for a second and then deselect automatically. How it can be managed if I come back to the tableview, the selected row should be highlighted.

Comment: Show what you have already tried. Add your code.

Comment: Add a  bool perpory isSelected to the model.   Set it in method RowSelected and  display the cell according to this property in GetCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing any code, but looks like the tableview is being reloaded in `viewDidAppear`. You may want to store the selected row index in `NSUserDefaults` or somewhere else to persist the selection between view loads/appearances.

Make sure you are setting it selected *after* the tableview reloads as well, using an appropriate delegate method. Again, without any code to look at, it's hard to see where - and which order - you're doing this, but an example (Swift):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1 {
        cell.selected = true
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could set the selected property in your datasource directly, and then you could do:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    datasource[indexPath.row].selected == true {
        cell.selected = true
    }
}
```

If you do it this way, then the selected row will always be set correctly every time the tableview is loaded.

(Full disclosure, I'm not a Xamarin dev, so I'm not sure how those translate from Swift/Obj-C to Xamarin)

Comment: Yes, it is reloaded it comes back. But I have the selected row value. And in tableviewcell I select it again via this.Selected=true. Row get selected for a second but then deselect automatically. How I can persist that selected row in case tableview reloaded?

Comment: Sounds like the reload ends after you’ve set it to selected. In which delegate method are you setting it to selected?